# Can't open Task Manager

Tags: windows-7, task-manager

When I right click on my task bar and click on **Start Task Manager** it gives me an error

> Windows cannot find
>   "C:\windows\system32\taskmgr.exe" Make
>   sure you have typed the name correctly
>   and try again.

So I tried executing task manager from system32 directory, still it gives me the same error.

Has my task manager gone corrupt ? If so how can I reinstall it?

Thanks.

---

Additional information for the case:

- running `sfc /verifyonly` resulted in `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.`
- On Windows 7 Home Premium Engish 64bit: size of "C:\Windows\System32\taskmgr.exe" is 257 024 bytes, it's md5 is 09f7401d56f2393c6ca534ff0241a590, crc-32 is d5b3f6f7.
- Permissions of taskmgr.exe are: `Read & execute + Read` for SYSTEM, Administrators and Users, `Full Control` for TrustedInstaller
- virustotal.com says [the file is virus-free](https://www.virustotal.com/file/50f2abb613df4813ce74f3b0df080497f689dfcad11f0fc7cd5ea4cdaf093bdf/analysis/1330949925/)
- in Windows Logs/Application I found a warning by winlogon saying `The Windows logon process has failed to spawn a user application. Application name: taskmgr.exe. Command line parameters: taskmgr.exe /3 .` that is apparently relavant to the problem,
- in Windows Logs/System I found an error by "VDS Basic Provider" saying `Unexpected failure. Error code: 490@01010004` that is apparently relavant to the problem

Comment: As a short-term option, if you just need to kill off some tasks, the FAR Manager (free and open source) includes a built-in process viewer (press Alt-F2 then the number 0) that can do this.  I find that it will work even when SpyWare is blocking Windows Task Manager:  http://www.farmanager.com/

Comment: Are you sure your system is clean, (as some viruses stop TaskMgr from running so you can't kill the virus)?

Comment: @Randolf Richardson Thanks for an alternative solution, but I don't need to kill any process. It's just I want to experiment with the old task manager.

Comment: @sgmoore Yeah, I messed up with the task manager a week ago : )

Comment: Sfc may be able to fix.

Comment: @sgmoore  What is Sfc ? Sorry for the ignorance.

Comment: System File Checker. Type SFC from an cmd prompt (running as administrator) for more details. It is designed to check that your system files have not been overwritten or corrupted.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

1. Download [sysinternals suite](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb842062) from microsoft technet and unpack.
2. Find and run `procexp.exe`.
3. Click in Options menu on Replace Task Manager and than Restore Task Manager.
4. Click **Ctrl+Alt+Del** or on taskbar Run Taskmanager.
   Settings are **restored** and **MS Taskmanager** works fine. Because of my habit I can´t work without **sysinternals**.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653

Comment: For some reasons it only shows Replace Task Manager in the options menu.

Comment: That's OK, Click Replace Task Manager twice. This will restore the original Task manager.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't notice the check mark besides it. I feel so stupid.

Comment: don't forget to run as administrator...

Comment: I would suggest to stop after step 2, cause procexp.exe I find superior to default task manager

Answer (score 2):

Process explorer by Sysinternals is one solution but there is another.

Use the built in System File Checker tool in Windows 7

Open a run command box or elevated command prompt and type in

sfc /scannow

it will now scan all your Windows system files and replace any that are missing or corrupt.

[Source of Information](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I could not even fix it with process explorer. The culprit was the value "**Debugger**" under `"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe"`. Some older installation of Process Explorer which had not been properly uninstalled had registered itself as the debugger of `taskmgr.exe` by storing its path in there, but that path did not exist anymore, so windows would refuse to run taskmgr.exe because it could not find the debugger for it. Deleting the "**Debugger**" value fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

1. Right click on computer > properties > system protection.
2. Create a restore point called Before.
3. Locate the task manager file.
4. Delete the file.
5. Create a restore point called After.
6. Open system restore.
7. Click next.

Your computer will restart during the process.

Answer (score 0):

Your "task manager" has not gone corrupt.  What the error message is telling you is that it can't be found at all.  Looks like the file that is the task manager executable has been deleted somehow.

`taskmgr.exe` is part of a standard Windows install and isn't an optional component.  So the fact that it is missing means someone has accidentally or intentionally deleted it.  One then is forced to wonder what other essential Windows files might be missing.  If you cannot account for this file being deleted for any reason, I'd suggest a reformat/reinstallation.  You don't know what else could be missing.

In the meantime, @xxl3ww is correct, Sysinternal's Process Explorer is much better than the built-in Task Manager of Windows, and you can use it if you need a program with the same capability.

Comment: I don't wish to reinstallation. Will the old task manger work if I copy it from my friends computer ?

Answer (score 0):

To change back from procexp.exe to original task manager: windows 7 Pro 64 bit
You can delete HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe in your registry to restore your original system task manager. Leave the "default" there.

Comment: This appears to be a comment on the answer by xxl3ww.