# Windows 7/8 - restore default task manager?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, task-manager

Does anyone know how to restore the default task manager in Windows 7/8? I've installed a 3rd party Task Manager (Process Hacker) but I want to switch back and I can't figure out how.

Comment: Just uninstall it through `control panel`.

Comment: I'd like to be able to switch between the two without uninstalling.

Comment: ok, so I uninstalled just to see what would happen and now I get "Windows cannot find 'c:\windows\system32\taskmgr.exe'"

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/271351/cant-open-task-manager  I followed those instructions and I'm back to stock now!  So it was sort of a two step process, uninstall Process Hacker then run Process Explorer and do the replace task manager option twice.

Comment: http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/forums/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=242

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed the instructions in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/271351/cant-open-task-manager) and I'm back to stock now. So it was sort of a two step process,

1. Uninstall Process Hacker
2. Then run Process Explorer and do the replace task manager option twice.

Comment: The key is to run the replace option twice; that is, if you've ran the replace option, run it again.

Answer (score 20):

Delete the registry following registry entry:

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe
```

Just tested it with process Explorer. The entry doesn't exist on Windows 7, unless I select "Replace task manager" within Process Explorer.

Comment: Isn't the question about Process Hacker rather than Process Explorer?

Comment: Here is the path i found on my Windows 10 PC``Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe``

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev it is the same principle. Both programs aim to replace the default taskmgr.exe

Process Explorer 64bit has a bug where it does not restore default taskmgr on Windows 10, so Bonsi's solution works perfectly!

Comment: I didn't delete `taskmgr.exe` instead I deleted `taskmgr.exe/debugger`. Works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall Process Hacker and get the [portable](http://sourceforge.net/projects/processhacker/files/processhacker2/processhacker-2.28-bin.zip/download) version, this will not replace the default Task Manager.

Comment: It can be configured to do so. options - > advanced -> Check "replace task manager with process hacker"

Answer (score -1):

To run both (since it seems that it overwrites the original task manager), copy the default task manager to another location before you install process hacker... then you can run it by clicking the icon like any other program

Answer (score -1):

Just go to options/advanced tab. Uncheck "replace task manager with process hacker"

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted. I don't use process hacker, but I would expect this to work.